# Mootools Element.fx conflict with jquery 1.5

Tags: mootools

I'm trying to use the element.fx effect from mootools as shown [here](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/) but it seems like its conflicting with jquery 1.5.

when I remove    it starts working again.  Any ideas on a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `document.id('my_dom_element')` instead of `$('my_dom_element')` when you are trying to use `MooTools` functions. You can also use `jQuery`'s `noConflicts()` method.

Comment: You don't need to do anything of the aforementioned. Just include MooTools *after* jQuery. MooTools is smart enough not to steal the *$* function if it's already being used.

Comment: Oskar is right, but you would still have to retrieve a mootools element in order to call mootools methods, and how are you going to retrieve a mootools element if `$` belongs to jQuery? `document.id` or `$$` are the 2 most obvious ways.